# wget on links without extensions

Tags: wget

I'm testing wget on one of my sites, it's structured like this:

```
<a href="/stuff/fancy-stub-url">Fancy Stub</a>
<a href="/stuff/more-fancy-seo-link">Seo Link</a>
<a href="/stuff/somethingIdontwant/#blah">Don't Download me</a>
```

Inside each of those links, there's a .png I want.

```
wget http://example.com/landing-page \
    --recursive \
    --level=2 \
    --accept '[a-zA-Z-]+',*.png \
    --force-html \
    --base=http://example.com
```

The reason I thought I needed `--level=2` with `--recursive` is because the `/more-fancy-seo-link` had the .png files, so I would need to hit them and then hit the .png files contained within. This is wrong, because the `/more-fancy-seo-link` pages are downloaded and *not* followed because they don't have the extension. How do I get wget to follow my SEO links, and then download the .png files in them?

Answer (score 1):

--force-html and --base only work with the -i option.

Your '*.png' is not quoted from the shell, so will be being substituted. You could try quoting it.

```
wget http://example.com/landing-page \
    --recursive \
    --level=2 \
    --accept '[a-zA-Z-]+,*.png'
```

If this fails, you could try:

```
wget http://example.com/landing-page -O - | \
    wget -i - \
        --recursive \
        --level=2 \
        --accept '*.png' \
        --force-html \
        --base=http://example.com
```

This gets the HTML file and pipes it to a second wget instance to get the PNGs.